# Глобальная переменная в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Есть программа с авторизацией. Мне необходимо каким то образом запомнить значение id работника и потом использовать его на формах в программе, причем формы программы являются отдельными DLL библиотеками.

Comment: "являются отдельными библиотеками" - уточните, как именно

Comment: Передавать этот id в каждую dll. Или, что правильнее менять дизайн приложения. Зачем визуальной форме какой-то id? Ей нужно отобразить данные и вернуть модифицированные. Все

Comment: В одной из форм мне необходимо использовать id работника для того чтобы отобразить  его данные в договоре формируемом этой формой

Comment: Если нужно только в паре форм, то передавайте параметр туда аргументами вызова.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для передачи глобальных переменных (данных, значений), рекомендуют использовать БД, как вариант sqlite или на крайний случай использовать сохранение в файл (пример: json), а DLL пускай от туда считывают, записывают или удаляют.... вроде таким образом решали эту проблему... и завтра может понадобиться не только одну глобальную переменную передавать :-)